# Run MR pipeline on “Run pipeline” button

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline

We use an on-prem GitLab server. One of the rules for launching our MR pipeline is its state. It should not be **Draft** or **WIP**, as I stated below.

```
  rules:
  - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /^WIP/ || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /^Draft/
    when: never
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
```

But in this form, it does not start in all cases with the error: “**No stages/jobs for this pipeline**”. Our developers want the MR pipeline to start when you click on the “**Run pipeline**” button in the “pipelines” section of the current MR. I did not find any indicator for clicking on this button, neither in the webhook nor anywhere else. I tried to use only `when: manual`, `if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"` and many other rules, but still no luck. Is there a way to make an exception to run the pipeline in this case, but keep it for the rest?

Answer (score 0):

you have to be aware the rules are evaluated in order, and as soon as one applies the evaluation is stopped.

> Rules are evaluated when the pipeline is created, and evaluated in order until the first match. When a match is found, the job is either included or excluded from the pipeline, depending on the configuration.
> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

this means, if you put `- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'` as the first rule, it will be evaluated first. this means if somebody triggers it via web, it does not matter if it is a draft or not.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify. There are two different "Run pipeline" buttons, one in the "Pipelines" section and another in "Merge requests" as you can see on these screenshots:
https://prnt.sc/20147f1
https://prnt.sc/201481q

The rule `- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'` will work only for the former. It won't for the latter as GitLab sees it as a `merge_request_event`, not the `web`. I need to run it in both cases but I can't find a way to trace the button push in the second one.